# Uploading and Styling File With PHP and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a form where the admins will be uploading more then 2 pictures at a time, i had been using the basic HTML file input style, however i want to do more with it as i am using a beautiful admin theme from themeforest, (the author haven't included the styled file input element in skin), i want to do it manually. which should meet the following requirement

> a) A styled file input element should
>   be displayed first
>
> b) When the user gives the file input
>   it should automatically upload the
>   file using php
>
> c)while uploading the file i want to
>   see the file upload progress with tool
>   tip
>
> d)once all the files are uploaded the
>   user should be able to process the
>   form with already uploaded file.

I want to admit that i have a very basic understanding of how javascript and Jquery works,  however i am quite good at PHP, HTML and CSS.

I want some kinda tutorial regarding how do i style my file input to fill my need.

i am searching something like this.. [File Upload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/3-0/showcase/single-file-button/)

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that fulfills all your requirements in a way that works with most browsers at the moment is a Flash-based uploader like [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org) or [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).

Comment: Pekka you are the greatest in StackOverflow, everytime i post a question i wish you answer it. thank you so much. i am going with Uploadify. i have to find a nice tutorial now how to embed it using PHP. :):) Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use SWFUpload. Look its [FEATURES DEMO](http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/featuresdemo/index.php). It has almost everything.